# Python: pandas apply vs. map

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am struggling to understand how `df.apply()`exactly works.

My problem is as follows: I have a dataframe `df`. Now I want to search in several columns for certain strings. If the string is found in any of the columns I want to add for each row where the string is found a "label" (in a new column).

I am able to solve the problem with `map` and `applymap`(see below).

However, I would expect that the better solution would be to use  `apply`as it applies a function to an entire column.

#### **Question**:  Is this not possible using `apply`? Where is my mistake?

Here are my solutions for using `map` and `applymap`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list("ABCDZ"),list("EAGHY"), list("IJKLA")], columns = ["h1","h2","h3","h4", "h5"])
```

#### Solution using `map`

```
def setlabel_func(column):
    return df[column].str.contains("A")

mask = sum(map(setlabel_func, ["h1","h5"]))
df.ix[mask==1,"New Column"] = "Label"
```

#### Solution using `applymap`

```
mask = df[["h1","h5"]].applymap(lambda el: True if re.match("A",el) else False).T.any()
df.ix[mask == True, "New Column"] = "Label"
```

For `apply`I don't know how to pass the two columns into the function / or maybe don't understand the mechanics at all ;-)

```
def setlabel_func(column):
    return df[column].str.contains("A")

df.apply(setlabel_func(["h1","h5"]),axis = 1)
```

Above gives me alert.

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Any advice? Please note that the search function in my real application is more complex and requires a regex function which is why I use `.str.contain` in the first place.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your response. My expected output is what solutions for `map` and `applymap` return. Sorry, I don't know how to paste in my output here? How do you do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solutions are use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for get at least one `True` per row:

```
print (df[['h1', 'h5']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A')))
      h1     h5
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False   True

print (df[['h1', 'h5']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A')).any(1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

---

```
df['new'] = np.where(df[['h1','h5']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A')).any(1),
                     'Label', '')

print (df)
  h1 h2 h3 h4 h5    new
0  A  B  C  D  Z  Label
1  E  A  G  H  Y       
2  I  J  K  L  A  Label
```

---

```
mask = df[['h1', 'h5']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A')).any(1)
df.loc[mask, 'New'] = 'Label'
print (df)
  h1 h2 h3 h4 h5    New
0  A  B  C  D  Z  Label
1  E  A  G  H  Y    NaN
2  I  J  K  L  A  Label
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. np.where is new to me. This will improve all my previous code significantly :-)

Answer (score 5):

`pd.DataFrame.apply` iterates over each column, passing the column as a `pd.Series` to the function being applied.  In you case, the function you're trying to apply doesn't lend itself to being used in `apply`

Do this instead to get your idea to work

```
mask = df[['h1', 'h5']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A').any(), 1)
df.loc[mask, 'New Column'] = 'Label'

  h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 New Column
0  A  B  C  D  Z      Label
1  E  A  G  H  Y        NaN
2  I  J  K  L  A      Label

​
```

Comment: Great. Works just fine. Thanks for your swift reply.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [23]: df['new'] = np.where(df[['h1','h5']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('A'))
                                             .sum(1) > 0,
                              'Label', '')

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
  h1 h2 h3 h4 h5    new
0  A  B  C  D  Z  Label
1  E  A  G  H  Y
2  I  J  K  L  A  Label
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. np.where is new to me. This will improve all my previous code significantly :-)

Comment: @FredMaster, glad i could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Others have given good alternative methods. **Here is a way to use apply 'row wise' (axis=1)** to get your new column indicating presence of "A" for a bunch of columns.

If you are passed a row, you can just join the strings together into one big string and then use a string comparison ("in") see below. here I am combing all columns, but you can do it with just H1 and h5 easily.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list("ABCDZ"),list("EAGHY"), list("IJKLA")], columns = ["h1","h2","h3","h4", "h5"])

def dothat(row):
    sep = ""
    return "A" in sep.join(row['h1':'h5'])
df['NewColumn'] = df.apply(dothat,axis=1)
```

This just squashes squashes each row into one string (e.g. ABCDZ) and looks for "A". This is not that efficient though if you just want to quit the first time you find the string then combining all the columns could be a waste of time. You could easily change the function to look column by column and quit (return true) when it finds a hit.